# Oracle error with Data pump export

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-04063

I am getting the following error. It doesn't happen to all the time, but once it starts, it won't stop.

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
ORA-39125: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.GET_TABLE_DATA_OBJECTS while calling DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_XML_CLOB []
ORA-31642: the following SQL statement fails: 
BEGIN "DMSYS"."DBMS_DM_MODEL_EXP".SCHEMA_CALLOUT(:1,0,1,'10.02.00.03.00'); END;
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 907
ORA-04063: package body "DMSYS.DBMS_DM_IMP_INTERNAL" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "DMSYS.DBMS_DM_IMP_INTERNAL"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6228
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
000007FFA0B608F8     14916  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
000007FFA0B608F8      6293  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
000007FFA0B608F8      9108  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
000007FFA0B608F8      1881  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
000007FFA0B608F8      6854  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
000007FFA0B608F8      1259  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
000007FFBC77F128         2  anonymous block
Job "SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_90" stopped due to fatal error at 12:31:55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: the error doesn't matter because the datamining is not used. The export still occurs.

It appears that the reason is that the DMSYS package was INVALID according to the following query

```
SQL> connect system/passwd
SQL> set lines 200
SQL> select status, 
            object_id, 
            object_type, 
            owner||'.'||object_name "OWNER.OBJECT"
     from   dba_objects 
     where  status != 'VALID' 
     order  by 4,2;
```

The following is supposed to fix the issue, but we do not have the data mining package installed.

```
SQL> CONNECT dmsys/dmsys
ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked
Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

SQL> CONNECT / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> ALTER USER dmsys IDENTIFIED BY dmsys ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
User altered.

SQL> CONNECT dmsys/dmsys
Connected.

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/dm/admin/dmutil.plb
Package created.
Package created.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may turn out not to be helpful, but I'd be interested to know what the errors in the package body `DMSYS.DBMS_DM_IMP_INTERNAL` are.  Running

```
SHOW ERRORS PACKAGE BODY DMSYS.DBMS_DM_IMP_INTERNAL;
```

in SQL*Plus should list them.